# I need to filter out some contents from RDD using pyspark

Tags: hadoop, lambda, filter, hdfs, pyspark

I need to extract several columns from a tab delmited file stored in HDFS.

I am able to read from HDFS into an RDD and split the rows into lists, but I don't know how to get the columns I care about..

My code:

```
raw_file = sc.textFile("hdfs.......tsv")
rdd = raw_file.map(lambda line: line.split('\t'))
```

Each column in newfile contains the same type of stuff, and I want to extract column 26, 80, 109, 452 and put them into a list.

I tried:

```
filtered = rdd.filter(lambda line: append(line[26]), append(line[80]), append(line[109], append(line[452])).collect()
```

but obviously there is no append method. So what do I do?

Comment: you split a "line" which gives you a list, then you check if "http" is in that list. You're never checking if the element in that list starts with "http".

Comment: You do, but you state you want to check if the list contains an item that starts with http. That's kinda different, don't you think?

Comment: I just want to extract four columns from pipelinedRDD

Answer (score 0):

Filter is used to return or omit **rows** based on some criteria.

```
rdd = sc.range(10)
even = rdd.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
even.collect()
# Out: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

What you're looking for is map. Map is used to transform (or in your case extract parts of) a row. Let's use an rdd of list of letters as an example. If I only want the 1st, 3rd, and 5th elements (columns), I can use a map to extract them.

```
rdd = sc.range(2).map(lambda i: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
print rdd.collect()
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]

mapped = rdd.map(lambda r: [r[1], r[3], r[5]])
print mapped.collect()
# [['b', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

Filter acts on rows, Map acts on data *inside* rows